# How to position a button at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native component and I am trying to put the touchable opacity button at the bottom of the map(but over the map with zIndex). But for some reason I can't achieve this. I have provided part of the code as following. also I don't understand why the button is appearing at the top before the map? i have also attached a photo of how the app looks like for different codes.[image]
[image]

```
 return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{paddingHorizontal:4,paddingTop:12}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:16,fontWeight:"bold",marginLeft:6}}>Please Type your address in the box below</Text>
      <Text>Your address is only used to filter neaerby listings of items.</Text>
      <TextInput 
      value={address}
      onChangeText={changeAddress}
      placeholder='Set Your address here'
      style={styles.Pasinput}
      />
      {
        address && !showmap && <ShowFlatlistAddress navigation={navigation} stAddrs={setAddress} addresses={addressToDisplay} flag={flagUrl} phoneC={phoneCode} stshowmap={setshowmap}/>
      }
      {
        showmap && 
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          zoomControlEnabled={true}
          style={{flex:1,height:height*1,width:width*1,...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}
          >
          <Marker
            draggable
            coordinate={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
            }}
            onDragEnd={
              (e) => alert(JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent.coordinate))
            }
            title={'Test Marker'}
            description={'This is a description of the marker'}
          />
        </MapView>
        <TouchableOpacity
        style={{position:"absolute",backgroundColor:"orange",zIndex:3,padding:12}}
        onPress={()=>{
          navigation.navigate("Verfication",{addressSet:address,flagC:flagUrl,phoneCodes:phoneCode})
        }}
        >
          <Text style={{fontSize:24,textAlign:"center"}}>Confirm Address</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      }
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this and say if it worked:

```
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {/* MapView codes */}
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "orange",
          padding: 12,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Verification", {
            addressSet: address,
            flagC: flagUrl,
            phoneCodes: phoneCode,
          });
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, textAlign: "center" }}>
          Confirm Address
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

replace you codes that shows the map, with {/* MapView codes */} part.
I wrapped the MapView and the Confirm Address button in a View with flex: 1.

Comment: It didn't work. the touchable opacity is still at the top of the map.

Answer (score 0):

pass a view as parent container and give it flex 1 . wrap up your safe area view inside it . then pass the button out side the safe area view

for ex -

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <SafeAreaView>
    //all content
    </SafeAreaView>
   <TouchableOpacity  style={{position:"absolute",backgroundColor:"orange",zIndex:3,padding:12}}
            onPress={()=>{
              navigation.navigate("Verfication",{addressSet:address,flagC:flagUrl,phoneCodes:phoneCode})
            }}
            >
              <Text style={{fontSize:24,textAlign:"center"}}>Confirm Address</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions here, but I think I know where the problem is.
When taking a look at [the position documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), the description for `absolute` explicitly says, that the element is positioned absolutely in **relation to its closest positioned ancestor**. For your code, that should currently be `<TextInput>`, since `<TouchableOpacity>` is the child of that component. That means, you would have to position the `<TouchableOpacity>` button relative to `<TextInput>`, in order to get it to the bottom - which is hard to do.

My proposal would be to take `<TouchableOpacity>` and put it on top of the document flow - for example as a direct child of `<body>`, or whatever is the top-most element in your app. This top-most element will most likely fill the whole page, which allows us the set `bottom: 0;` on `<TouchableOpacity>`, which will then mean: "Position this element at the bottom of this element, which is essentially the whole page - so position it at the bottom of the page".

There is one more requirement to accomplish this. [The position documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) explicitly says: closest to its first `positioned` ancestor. Therefore, `<body>` would need to get `position: relative;`. An element that has `position: relative;` counts as a positioned element, but essentially does not change it's position from its normal flow at all, which is good.

I do things like these all the time, and the only requirement is that `<TouchableOpacity>` is able to move to a different place in the App (which might not always be possible, but often times is).

If you can't do that, another option would be to have all current ancestors of `<TouchableOpacity>` be **un-positioned**, and only make the ancestor positioned with `position: relative;` where it would actually make sense to position `<TouchableOpacity>` absolutely in relation to. That could be `<body>`, but depending on your layout, might be some other element entirely.

Do write me a comment if this did not solve your problem or you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

add bottom:0 in your touchableOpacity styling

```
style={{
          backgroundColor: "orange",
          padding: 12,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          bottom:0
 }}
```